# Programmatically selecting items in winforms checkboxlist

Tags: winforms, checkboxlist

I can't figure out how to programmatically select items in checkboxlist.

This method of cource doesn't compile, but I want to show you what a result I want to get.

```
public ColumnsSelector(Dictionary<string, bool> dataPropertyNames)
            : this()
        {
            foreach (var item in dataPropertyNames)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.Key);
                checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item.Key)].Checked = item.Value;
            }
        }
```

How do you force with this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemcheckstate.aspx):

```
checkedListBox.SetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1, CheckedState.Checked);
```

which works for checked, unchecked, and indeterminate. You can also use [CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx):

```
checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.Key);
 checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1, item.Value);
```

or just

```
 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
```